# Are two vectors $\mathbf x, \mathbf y$ considered parallel if $\mathbf x=- \mathbf y$?

Tags: vectors

In my linear algebra class we discussed parallel vectors. However, I've come upon a homework question that has really confused me. I tried asking the professor, but he didn't understand what I was trying to say. Here is the question:

Determine whether the vectors emanating from the origin and terminating at the following points are parallel. Points: $(5, -6, 7)$ and $(-5, 6, -7)$.

Clearly, $(-5, 6, -7)$ is a multiple of $(5, -6, 7)$. Observe that $(-1)(-5, 6, -7)=(5, -6, 7)$. Also, even though we haven't discussed cross products I know the concept from calculus which says that when $\mathbf u \times \mathbf v= \mathbf 0$ the two vectors are parallel, so
$$\begin{vmatrix} \vec{i}&\vec{j}&\vec{k}\\ 5&-6&7\\-5&6&-7\end{vmatrix}=\vec{i}(42-42)-\vec{j}(-35+35)+\vec{k}(30-30)=\mathbf0$$

So my logic tells me that the two vectors are parallel, but I'm sure there must be a flaw with my understanding because the answer given says that these two vectors are not parallel. Can somebody please clarify or direct me to a similar post that can clear up my confusion?

Thanks a lot in advance!

(By the way the homework has already been submitted and returned to me, but this question was not one of the questions selected for grading)

Comment: Yes, they are parallel.

Comment: I would consider the answer given to be wrong, unless their notion of parallel includes pointing in the same direction; but this is unusual.

Comment: I would agree: yes, they are parallel. But maybe your book is using a non-standard definition? Somewhere in the text, they should clearly state what it means for two vectors to be parallel.

Comment: @BaronVT That's why I was confused. Their definition of parallel is, "Two nonzero vectors x and y are called parallel if y = tx for some nonzero real number t. (Thus nonzero vectors having the same or opposite directions are parallel.)"

Comment: Then either the solution guide is incorrect, or you have miscopied some detail of the problem (e.g. maybe it's $(5,-6,7)$ and $(-5,6,7)$)

Comment: @BaronVT, I checked once again to make sure I copied it correctly and I did, so I guess the solution is incorrect. I'm just glad that my understanding of this topic is not flawed like I thought it was.

Comment: Who is "they"? If the question comes from a textbook, please cite the author, title, and edition of the textbook, and the page numbers containing the definition of "parallel" and the exercise. Full quotations of the definition and the exercise would be ideal. Also, you can check online for errata. If the question comes directly from the professor, you should persist in getting an answer from him. Actually, you should do that either way!

Answer (score 2):

I would say, maybe you can write the as the term "anti-parallel".
Although even that, would just be a part of "parallel", more like a special case of it where the direction of the two vectors is in opposite direction.
I would go with the fact that the solution might be incorrect, unless the author really wants you to state "anti-parallel" instead of just "parallel".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 2):

Most writers define two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ to be *parallel* if there exists $k\neq0$ such that $\mathbf{x}=k\mathbf{y}$. By this definition then, the answer to your title question is "yes": Two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are parallel if $\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{y}$.

---

(Note though that a minority of writers define two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ to be *parallel* if there exists $k>0$ such that $\mathbf{x}=k\mathbf{y}$ and *anti-parallel* if there exists $k<0$ such that $\mathbf{x}=k\mathbf{y}$. By these definitions then, the answer to your title question is "no": Two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are **not** parallel if $\mathbf{x}=-\mathbf{y}$; instead, they are anti-parallel.)